# C# public datatype variable( get; private set) Why do we need set method if variable is already public?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I have coded previously in Java. In Java, instance variables are private so that no one accesses them directly, and we have public getters and setters to access them. But in C#, if the variable itself is not public, then we cannot have a `public set` method.  What is the need of the set method in the first place if the variable itself is public and we can access it directly?

Comment: Why a downvote?  I get the impression that this community is not very welcoming to new coders for clearing their doubts. Only experts discuss their problems with each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mapped Java concepts onto C# concepts in the wrong way.

First, note that in C# you can also write code as if you were in Java, with getter and setter methods and a private field. This C# code is perfectly fine, as far as the compiler is concerned:

```
private int foo;
public int getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
public void setFoo(int foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

but you will probably be frowned upon by other C# developers.

What you seem to be talking about in your question, are (automatically implemented) *properties*. They are basically syntactic sugar for this kind of "private field + getter + setter" pattern. When you do:

```
public int Foo { get; set; }
```

A private field, a setter and a getter are automatically generated. You can't access this field directly, however. You call the setter by doing `Foo = ...` and call the getter by accessing `Foo`'s value in any way.

The access modifier of the property dictates the access modifiers of the getter and setter, whereas the underlying field will always be private. So for the `Foo` property above, its getters and setters are both public.

Now what if I want different access modifiers for the getter and setter? I can do this:

```
public int Foo { get; private set; }
```

Now the getter is public but the setter is private. Now a Java developer might ask "why do I need a private setter?" because in Java, you could just set the field directly. But here, since the field is auto-generated and inaccessible to the programmer, a private setter is not meaningless.

Now you should understand why this is not allowed:

```
private int Foo { get; public set; }
```

This means that the getter is private but the setter is public, which means that the property can be set anywhere in the codebase, but only read from in the same class. Weird field to have, isn't it?

> What is the need of the set method in the first place if the variable itself is public and we can access it directly?

As I said, if you only have a getter, then the property can't even be set within the same class (except in the constructor), unlike in Java, where you can just set the underlying field directly.

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
private int _age = 0;
public int getAge(){
  return _age;
}
public void setAge(int value){
  _age = value;
}
```

In C#:

```
private int _age = 0;
public int Age{
  get {
    return _age;
  }
  set{
    _age = value;
  }
}
```

More or less the same thing don't you think? C# is more succinct IMHO. Other minor differences: properties have different icons to methods in IntelliSense, you don't use brackets when you "call" them and they only take one value (in the set form)

Horses for courses I suppose; the Java form would be legal in c# if you wanted to use it, though the c# form isn't available in Java. Typically C#ers use properties extensively because modern C# lets us hide the backing variable behind some syntactic sugar:

```
public int Age{ get; set; }
```

You don't use the backing variable at all in this form, just the public name regardless of whether you're inside or outside the class

-

The rest of your question is based on a misunderstanding so it can't really be answered; as you can see above the private variable is made accessible by the public property. We don't really use public variables in c#, only public properties. There is a lot more to say about properties, private gets and sets, readonly etc but that's more a job for [the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Answer (score -1):

method "get" = for set access to get value of variable. 
method "set" = for set access to modification of variable

C# provided developer to make variable only get a value, like we make a constant variable on java.